# cast uuid to varchar in postgres when I use sequelize

Tags: postgresql, uuid, sequelize.js

I have a table with a column named `_id` of which the type is `uuid`. I cast the type of `_id` from `uuid` to `varchar`, in order to select the records as follows:

```
SELECT "_id" FROM "records" WHERE "_id"::"varchar" LIKE '%1010%';
```

and it works well.

```
                 _id                  
--------------------------------------
 9a7a36d0-1010-11e5-a475-33082a4698d6
(1 row)
```

I use sequelize as ORM for operation postgres. how to build the query condition in sequelize?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I write the query condition as follows, and it works well. Is there any better solution?

```
{where: ['_id::"varchar" like ?', '%1010%']},
```